# next() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table structure:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="xx"></a>
  </td>
  <td>
    data
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 
    <img src="#" class="cc" />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="xx"></a>
  </td>
  <td>
    data2
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 
    <img src="#" class="cc" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Now, on load, 2nd and 4th row are hidden. On click of `<a>` its immediate next rows `<img>` should come into display.

For that i have written:

```
$("a.xx").click(function (event) {
  $(this).next(".cc").toggleClass();// not working
});
```

Any clue?

**EDIT:**

On click of 1st row's `<a>`, it should show 2nd row's `<img>` and on click of 3rd `<a>`, it should show 4th row's `<img>`, and only one `<img>` at a time.

**CSS**

```
.cc {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Based on further clarification, you want a second click to close an open image.

Do this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find("img.cc").toggle()
       .closest('tr').siblings('tr').find("img.cc").hide();
```

or this, which is a little more efficient:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find("img.cc").toggle(0, function() {
       var $th = $(this);
       if( $th.is(':visible') )
           $th.closest('tr').siblings('tr').find("img.cc").hide();
});
```

---

**EDIT:** Based on clarification, seems like you want to show the image in the next row, and hide the rest.

Do this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find("img.cc").show()
       .closest('tr').siblings('tr').find("img.cc").hide();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

---

**Original answer:**

Do this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find("img.cc").toggleClass('someClass');
```

jQuery's `.next()` only looks at the *siblings* of the element.

You need to traverse up to the `.closest()` `<tr>` element, get the `.next()` row, then `.find()` the `.cc` element.

- http://api.jquery.com/closest/
- http://api.jquery.com/next/
- http://api.jquery.com/find/

I also assume you're passing a class name to `.toggleClass()` instead of calling it without an argument.

Otherwise, to display the `<img>` you would probably use `.show()`.

Comment: I tried $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find("img.cc").toggleClass("cc"); but its only opening, not closing the <td>
if I click on first row then 2nd rows img should be in display mode, if I click on 3 rd row then any open image should close and 4 th row image should open

Comment: Thanks for ur help, but i think my qs is not clear, see now its working, but if I 2 nd time click on the <a> ideally it should close the <img>