# meaning of this jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I posted a question [next() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560381/next-not-working) and gota reply which is working fine, but can somebody explain me what exactly is going on here:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find("img.cc").toggle()
       .closest('tr').siblings('tr').find("img.cc").hide();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<tr>                              <<-- 1.)    <<-- 6.)
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="xx"></a>               <<-- we start here
  </td>
  <td>
    data
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>                              <<-- 2.)    <<--  5.)
  <td> 
    <img src="#" class="cc" />    <<-- 3.)    <<-- 4.)
  </td>
</tr>    
<tr>                              <<-- 6.)
  <td>
    <a href="#" class="xx"></a>
  </td>
  <td>
    data2
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>                              <<-- 6.)
  <td> 
    <img src="#" class="cc" />    <<-- 7.)
  </td>
</tr>
```

- **1.)** `$(this).closest('tr')`

  This line jumps to 1.)
- **2.)** `.next('tr')`

  We're arriving at 2.)
- **3.)** `.find("img.cc")`

  Now, we hopefully found element at 3.)
- **4.)** `.toggle()`

  We switch visibilty from element **4.)** (visible/hidden)
- **5.)** `.closest('tr')`

  We jump back to the closest parent `tr`
- **6.)** `siblings('tr')`

  We receive all `tr's` marked with **6.)**
- **7.)** `.find("img.cc").hide();`

  Find the `img.cc` within all siblings `tr's` -> 6.)
  and hide them.

Comment: very nice and concise way to express tree results.

Answer (score 3):

It does the following, each step related to the method called:

1. `.closest('tr')` - go from the current element up to the nearest `<tr>` ancestor (or itself, if it's already a `<tr>`).
2. `.next('tr')` - go to the next sibling row
3. `.find("img.cc")` - finds a `<img class="cc">` inside that row
4. `.toggle()` - toggle it (show if hidden, hide if shown)
5. `.closest('tr')` - go back up to the `<tr>`
6. `.siblings('tr')` - select all sibling (other) rows
7. `.find("img.cc")` - find all the `<img class="cc">` in them.
8. `.hide()` - hide them

It could be a bite more efficient though using [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to hop back in the chain, like this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find("img.cc").toggle()
       .end().siblings('tr').find("img.cc").hide();
```

Comment: I think that the `end()` is (or may) not be what he wanted.
see adardesign answer.

Comment: Nick - In my defense ;o) I thought about using `.end()` in my answer, but thought I should keep things as simple as possible. I'd say I may have been right. :o) +1

Answer (score 1):

This code is probably taken from in middle the context of a `function`

the first line says something like:

Starting from `this` (the element/s called on), Find the nearest (parent) `tr` then look for the `next` `tr`(meaning a brother of `this` parent) and `find` an `img` with the `class` of "cc"  and`toggle` its `display` value (meaning, if its visible then hide it and if its hidden show it.

The second line starts from where it finished, and says find a `img` with a `class` of "cc" in the `siblings` of the nearest (parent) `tr`'s next `tr` and hide that it.

Comment: Not my downvote, but you're missing the first traversal down to the `<img>` :)

Comment: Correct, for the sake of completeness i will finish it off :)

Answer (score 0):

Toggles visiblity of img.cc in the next table row and hides all other img.cc in the table.